# Do i need to have mac os and android studio on my setup?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am starting mobile app development in ionic framework.I have installed angular cli and ionic in my setup
. So I want to know should we also have mac os for ios app and android studio for android app to develop app in ionic for both platform.

Answer (score 1):

To build and publish apps for iOS you need Mac OS and xcode, there exist online Mac OS providers like [this](https://www.macincloud.com/) also.

Comment: What about using mac os in virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

To develop iOS native application MacOS is a must. Android apps can be developed on Windows or on MacOS devices.

If you have any restrictions on exposing the API services to the cloud, you will not be able to use the Cloud based MacOS (unless there is a secured tunneling from the cloud to your device network)

MacOS do not run on any VirtualBox.